# Use Factory Pattern in Laravel

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, repository, factory

I am working on a Laravel project and want to implement Factory and Repository pattern in my project. However, I still don't know where should I use Factory pattern? It's still very confusing. I understand that it's not necessary to use the Factory pattern for every single project but as a part of my study, I want to learn more about the combination of this 2 patterns. This is my code example. Hope I can get help and explains from you guys. Thank you.

```
class ProductFactory 
{
    public function create()
    {
       return new Product; 
    }
}




class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
   protected $productFactory; 

   public function __contruct(
      ProductFactory $productFactory
   )
   {
      $this->productFactory = $productFactory      
   }
   public function all()
   {
      return Product::all();
   }
   public function loadById($id);
   {
      return Product::find($id);
   }
   public function save($data,$id=NULL)
   {
       if($id != NULL){
         $product = $this->loadById($id)
       }
       else{
         $product = $this->productFactory->create(); 
       }
       return $product->fill($data)->save();
   }
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split the factory and repository. For example:

```
class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $product; 

    public function __contruct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    //...
}
```

But not necessary for DI in repository, your methods like all(), find() and etc. put in AbstractRepository. Your ProductRepositry:

```
    class ProductRepository extends AbstractRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
    {
        public function __contruct()
        {
           //model property in AbstractRepository
            $this->model = new Product();
        }
    }
```

If you want to write test for it, you may use laravel container:
AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind(Product::class, function ($app) {
    return new Product();
});
```

ProductRepository:

```
$this->model = app()->make(Product::class);
```

PS: i think factory useless, in most cases i use container. But in some difficult cases i use factory, for example:

```
class ProductFactory
{
     public static function create(int $type, array $attributes): ProductInterface
     {
          switch ($type) {
               case 'market':
                 return new MarketProductModel($attributes);
                 break;
               case 'shop':
                 $model = new ShopProductModel($attributes);
                 $model->setMathCoef(1.2);

                 return $model;
                 break;
               case 'something':
                 return new SomethingProductModel($attributes);
                 break;
          }
     }
}
```